# Matlab vector expansion

Tags: matlab, vector, transform, projection, expansion

I have a 1-D vector and need to "unproject"(sorry, I dont know how to tell it) it to 3D-space. If there is a built-in function to avoid loops?

A 2D example to clarify. I had

```
[1 2 3;
 4 5 6;
 7 8 9]
```

It has been projected to the first dimension. Gotten:

```
[6;
15;
24]
```

Now I need to "de-project" it and get:

```
[2 2 2;
 5 5 5;
 8 8 8]
```

Then I will repeat it for a set of angles.

This is like a Radon transform but in 3D. So do we have a function for such kind of action in 3D-space and (if I am lucky) for arbitrary angles of the axis of interest.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do it in 3D for this vector:

```
v = [6;15;24];

repmat(v, [1 3 3])/9
```

---

A generalized solution that will unproject any vector into a shape with your `requiredDimensions`:

```
v = [6;15;24];
requiredDimensions = 3;

n = numel(v);
myDims = [1 repmat(n,1,requiredDimensions - 1)];
repmat(v, myDims )/prod(myDims)
```

Comment: The current constructions of `myDims` assumes you want everything to be 'square' but should not be hard to adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing it.
Let `v` be the "projected vector" ( `v = [6;15;24;]` in your example ), and `d` be the desired number of columns ( `d = 3` in your example ), then:

```
>> v * ones( 1, d ) / d
```

Alternatively

```
>> repmat( v/d, [1 d] )
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2D:

```
B = sum(A')';

C = diag(B)*(ones(size(A))/size(A,2));

C =    
   2   2   2
   5   5   5
   8   8   8
```

It should be pretty straight forward to adapt to 3D.